# ImageView/layout rounded circular in XML

Tags: android, xml

I'd Like to make any image from my ImageView/Layout to be circular with a border.

I searched but couldn't find any useful information (anything that I tried didn't work).

Please find the screenshot[image]

Comment: use https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView or https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView

Comment: https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is this, 
https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: we need another imageview on top of imageview

Comment: you can use two different Image view and set their position using relative layout.